C# Task Based Multithreading Http Requests -> This operation is only allowed using a successfully authenticated context
I am trying to write a small async wrapper of an api that i want to run multi threaded.
It's also my first my time writing async/multithreaded code in C#
public class Session(string apiKey, HttpClient client) {
...
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _authSemaphore = new(1, 1);
...
public async Task<TaskResponseDto?> Solve(CreateTaskDto taskRequest, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { 
        var errorMessage = await SendAsync(taskRequest, Constants.TasksCreateUrl, cancellationToken);
        if ( errorMessage != null )  {
            ...
        }
        
        var taskResponse = await WaitForTaskAsync(taskRequest.TaskId, timeout, cancellationToken);
        if (taskResponse == null) {
            ...
        }
        
        return taskResponse;
    }

 private async Task<string?> SendAsync(object req, string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  {
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(req), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        
        var (responseMessage, statusCode) = await DoAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (responseMessage == null || !IsStatus2Xx(statusCode)) {
            ...
        }
        
        return null;
    }

private async Task<(string?, HttpStatusCode)> DoAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        await _authSemaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        try {
            refresh auth token if expired...
        }
        finally {
            _authSemaphore.Release();
        }
        
        ...

        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Token {_token}");
        try {
            using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
            return (content, response.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (...) {
          ...
        }
    }


All tasks share the same http client as the methods that I call are thread-safe.
It works fine when being ran by only one task. However when i try to run it with multiple tasks the catch block of the DoAsync method returns one of the following error messages, sometimes even 2 or all 3.
Unexpected error: This operation is only allowed using a successfully authenticated context.
Unexpected error: This method may not be called when another read operation is pending.
Unexpected error: This method may not be called when another write operation is pending.
In my application i call the Solve method of the wrapper with the await keyword.
I have my suspicion that another task is trying to access the http client and doing requests while the other tasks is not finished reading from it? Which is why i included "using..." at some parts but that didn't fix the problem.

What prevents you from using one HttpClient per thread?  The cost of doing that is almost certainly an order of magnitude less than your network latency cost.

You are making an http connection from a client to a server using a token.  Most server will only allow one connection between a client and server.  You are making multiple connections using different threads.  Make sure you use the same token with all threads and make sure you do not send a request until and previous request gets a response.  I would use a semaphore like WaitOne to make sure each thread gets a response before sending a 2nd request.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-8.0

HttpClient is supposed to be fully threadsafe, unless you're using a custom handler and done something wrong. Only the content stream cannot be read from concurrently. Can you post the full stack trace?

@RobertHarvey
After using a HttpClient per thread the issue has been resolved, thank you.

However i would still like to understand why there are issues with sharing one since its supposed to be threadsafe
@Charlieface here is the full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/p1URzG85

I suggest you file a issue/bug on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime
